# how to show json by javascript to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

hi I want a function like this! https://i.stack.imgur.com/p61fq.png

when I select the first "select tag"

the secoud "select tag" show undefined

but in this picture the CONSOLE area is exactly show what I want.

My problem is...how to show the data in second "select tag"?

I think it's something wrong in my javascript.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
      url: "dropdownServlet",
      data: dataString,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          $("#dropdown2").html("");
            $.each(data, function(){
                $.each(this,function(){
                    $("#dropdown2").append("<option>"+data.CiytName+"</option>");   
                });
            });            
     },
```

and this's my json data

```
[{"CityId":"4","CityName":"Vancouver"},{"CityId":"5","CityName":"Toronto"}]
```

Comment: For starters, your code is incorrectly looking for data.CiytName...

Comment: Why are you doing 2 foreach loops? That appears wrong, also data.CiytName should be data.CityName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is this:

```
    $.each(data, function(_, ob){
        $("#dropdown2").append("<option>"+ob.CityName+"</option>");   

   });
```

1. Since your data is already `[{"CityId":"4","CityName":"Vancouver"},{"CityId":"5","CityName":"Toronto"}]` you just need to use one level of `$.each` iteration and 
   `data.CiytName` has 2 issues,
2. data is the original object (Not the object of this iteration)
3. `CiytName` has a typo.

Just my suggestion not to append in the $.each loop iteration to reduce the number of DOM operations especially when you have huge data in your json to be appended as option.

```
      var select = $('<select/>'); //Create a temp element.
        $.each(data, function(){
                select.append("<option>"+ob.CityName+"</option>");   //append to the temp element 
         });       

        $("#dropdown2").html(select.html());  //finally fill in the dropdown with your latest options.
```

Refer [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: thanks lot! 
Do you know about this $.each(data,function(_,ob) tutorial resource can I learn?

Comment: @劉承緯 Updated my answer with reference link. Did this resolve your issue?

Comment: **+1** from me as well. Explained it perfectly.